# Efecto CSS y JS

Tags: javascript, css

Estoy realizando un `slide` pero es un `split screen`. He conseguido hacer el efecto pero aun me falta realizar lo ultimo que es posicionar unos textos en las esquinas en el momento que el puntero hace hover sobre una imagen. Mi intencion es crear uno parecido al de [esta](https://www.emerson.com/en-us) pagina. Hasta el momento tengo esto..

```css
#wrapper-personalizado{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  min-height:40vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layer{
  position: absolute;
  width:100vw;
  min-height: 40vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layer .content-wrap{
  position: absolute;
  width:100vw;
  min-height: 40vw;
}

.layer .content-body{
  width:25%;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  color:#fff;
  z-index:1
}

.layer img{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.layer h1{
  font-size:2em;
}

.bottom{
  background:#222;
  z-index:1;
  transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.63, 0.04, 0.69, 1.01);
}

.bottom:hover ~ .top {
    width: calc(5vw + 1150px);
}

.bottom .content-body{
  right:5%;
  transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.63, 0.04, 0.69, 1.01);
}

.bottom:hover .content-body {
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(50%)
}

.bottom h1{
  color:#FDAB00;
}

.top{
  background:#eee;
  color:#222;
  z-index:2;
}

.top .content-body{
  left: 5%;
  transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.63, 0.04, 0.69, 1.01) 
}

.skewed .top{
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  margin-left:-1000px;
  width: calc(50vw + 1000px);
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.63, 0.04, 0.69, 1.01) 
}

.skewed .top:hover {
  width: calc(105vw + 750px);
}

.skewed .top:hover .content-body {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.skewed .top .content-wrap{
  transform: skew(20deg);
  margin-left:1000px;
}

@media(max-width:1023px){
  
  body{
    font-size:75%;
  }
  
  .skewed{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="skewed flex" id="wrapper-personalizado">
        <div class="layer bottom" id="one">
            <div class="content-wrap">
                <div class="content-body">
                    <h1>AUTOMATIZACIÓN INDUSTRIAL</h1>
                    <a href="<?php echo the_field('boton_hero'); ?>" class="theme-btn">Conoce más</a>
                </div>
                <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/seamartini/seamartini1703/seamartini170300041/72903056-herramienta-de-trabajo-instrumento-y-equipo-para-la-construcción-y-la-reparación-de-patrón-de-trabajo-sin-pro.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="layer top" id="two">
            <div class="content-wrap">
                <div class="content-body">
                    <h1>MANEJO DE MATERIALES</h1>
                    <a href="<?php echo the_field('boton__hero_2'); ?>" class="theme-btn">Conoce más</a>
                </div>
                <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/donatas1205/donatas12051204/donatas1205120400043/13013042-carpintería-herramientas-de-construcción-de-hardware-debajo-de-la-tabla-de-madera.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que al momento en que se haga el split mis textos se muestren como la siguiente manera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pueden ver lo que tengo en la siguiente [pagina](https://www.fgsaltillo.com/)

Comment: En tu [página](https://www.fgsaltillo.com/) parece estar funcionando, ¿ya lo resolviste?

Comment: si, lo resolvi en la madrugada

Comment: Puedes añadir una respuesta con la solución, por si alguien tiene un problema similar.

Comment: Puedes añadir una respuesta con la solución, por si alguien tiene un problema similar.

Comment: Deberias compartir la solución y marcarla como resuelta.